# iOS build failed using Codemagic [Works fine with Xcode]

Tags: ios, continuous-delivery, codemagic

**The build is done successfully in Xcode** but when I build it using code magic it fails. Below is my log for build fail.

Below is the output which I received from code magic. It shows some errors in firebase and audience network plugin but it is not generated in Xcode. I am not getting exact errors here.

```
    == Building for iOS ==

    <span style="color:#268BD2">&gt; xcode-project use-profiles</span>
Configure code signing settings
Searching for files matching /Users/builder/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/*.mobileprovision

Searching for files matching /Users/builder/clone/**/*.xcodeproj
<span style="color:#859900">Completed configuring code signing settings</span>
 <span style="color:#268BD2">- Using profile "IOS Oct 2020" [-bb52-4b20-8f43-406ff4121bfb] for target "Runner" [Debug] from project "Runner"</span>
 <span style="color:#268BD2">- Using profile "IOS Oct 2020" [-bb52-4b20-8f43-406ff4121bfb] for target "Runner" [Profile] from project "Runner"</span>
 <span style="color:#268BD2">- Using profile "IOS Oct 2020" [-bb52-4b20-8f43-406ff4121bfb] for target "Runner" [Release] from project "Runner"</span>
<span style="color:#859900">Generated options for exporting IPA</span>
 <span style="color:#268BD2">- Method: app-store</span>
 <span style="color:#268BD2">- Provisioning Profiles:</span>
     <span style="color:#268BD2">- .linuxhandbook: IOS Oct 2020</span>
 <span style="color:#268BD2">- Signing Certificate: Apple Distribution</span>
 <span style="color:#268BD2">- Signing Style: manual</span>
 <span style="color:#268BD2">- Team Id: C6272K7</span>
<span style="color:#859900">Saved export options to /Users/builder/export_options.plist</span>

<span style="color:#268BD2">&gt; /usr/local/bin/flutter build ios --release --no-codesign</span>
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
Warning
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Your Flutter application is created using an older version of the Android
embedding. It's being deprecated in favor of Android embedding v2. Follow the
steps at

https://flutter.dev/go/android-project-migration

to migrate your project.
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━

Warning: Building for device with codesigning disabled. You will have to manually codesign before deploying to device.
Building androing.linuxhandbook for device (ios-release)...
Running pod install...                                            116.1s
Running Xcode build...                                          
Xcode build done.                                           128.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    &lt;module-includes&gt;:1:9: note: in file included from &lt;module-includes&gt;:1:
    #import "Headers/FBAudienceNetwork.h"
            ^
    
                                     ^
    /Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources/Public/FIRMessaging.h:219:1: note: 'FIRMessagingRemoteMessage' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    __deprecated_msg(
    ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging-prefix.pch:2:
    In module 'Foundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode-12.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
    In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode-12.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Applications/Xcode-12.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:
    /Applications/Xcode-12.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:200:48: note: expanded from macro '__deprecated_msg'
            #define __deprecated_msg(_msg) __attribute__((__deprecated__(_msg)))
                                                          ^
    /Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:141:30: warning: 'shouldEstablishDirectChannel' is deprecated: FCM direct channel is deprecated, please use APNs channel for downstream message delivery. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        [FIRMessaging messaging].shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true;
                                 ^
    In module 'FirebaseMessaging' imported from /Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:76:
    /Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources/Public/FIRMessaging.h:283:56: note: 'shouldEstablishDirectChannel' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @property(nonatomic) BOOL shouldEstablishDirectChannel DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(
                                                           ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging-prefix.pch:2:
    In module 'Foundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode-12.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
    In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode-12.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Applications/Xcode-12.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:
    /Applications/Xcode-12.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:181:64: note: expanded from macro 'DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE'
                #define DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(s) __attribute__((deprecated(s)))
                                                                   ^
    /Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:196:52: warning: 'appData' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      [self didReceiveRemoteNotification:remoteMessage.appData];
                                                       ^
    In module 'FirebaseMessaging' imported from /Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:76:
    /Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources/Public/FIRMessaging.h:226:62: note: 'appData' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @property(nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSDictionary *appData DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE;
                                                                 ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging-prefix.pch:2:
    In module 'Foundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode-12.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
    In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode-12.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Applications/Xcode-12.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:
    /Applications/Xcode-12.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:179:60: note: expanded from macro 'DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE'
            #define DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE        __attribute__((deprecated))
                                                               ^
    /Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:306:1: warning: implementing deprecated method [-Wdeprecated-implementations]
    - (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging
    ^
    In module 'FirebaseMessaging' imported from /Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:76:
    /Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources/Public/FIRMessaging.h:253:1: note: method 'messaging:didReceiveMessage:' declared here
    - (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging
    ^
    /Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:308:63: warning: 'appData' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      [_channel invokeMethod:@"onMessage" arguments:remoteMessage.appData];
                                                                  ^
    In module 'FirebaseMessaging' imported from /Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:76:
    /Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources/Public/FIRMessaging.h:226:62: note: 'appData' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @property(nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSDictionary *appData DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE;
                                                                 ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging-prefix.pch:2:
    In module 'Foundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode-12.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
    In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode-12.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Applications/Xcode-12.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:
    /Applications/Xcode-12.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:179:60: note: expanded from macro 'DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE'
            #define DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE        __attribute__((deprecated))
                                                               ^
    6 warnings generated.
    /bin/sh: /Users/rushabhshah/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh: No such file or directory
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'webview_flutter' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'url_launcher' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'store_redirect' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'sqflite' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'shared_preferences' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'share' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'path_provider' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'package_info' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'firebase_messaging' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The use of Swift 3 @objc inference in Swift 4 mode is deprecated. Please address deprecated @objc inference warnings, test your code with “Use of deprecated Swift 3 @objc inference” logging enabled, and then disable inference by changing the "Swift 3 @objc Inference" build setting to "Default" for the "Runner" target. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    warning: The use of Swift 3 @objc inference in Swift 4 mode is deprecated. Please address deprecated @objc inference warnings, test your code with “Use of deprecated Swift 3 @objc inference” logging enabled, and then disable inference by changing the "Swift 3 @objc Inference" build setting to "Default" for the "Runner" target. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'Protobuf' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'PromisesObjC' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'GoogleUtilities' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'GoogleDataTransport' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseMessaging' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseInstanceID' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseInstallations' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseCoreDiagnostics' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseCore' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'GoogleAppMeasurement' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseAnalytics' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'Firebase' from project 'Pods')

Encountered error while building for device.
```

Comment: As it says in the output, you need to migrate your project to a newer version of  Android
embedding.

Comment: Is it required for iOS build? And it is just warning! @koen

Comment: If you look below the build failed part, there are a lot of messages about deprecated code, so it could still be related to your crash..

Comment: Thanks for your response. But when I am building the same with XCode it works fine. Archive is build properly. It just not build with Code magic. Can you please guide me on that? @koen

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with Code Magic.

Comment: No problem. Thanks! @koen

Answer (score 1):

check this part of the error output

```
/Users/rushabhshah/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh: No such file or directory
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

you use absolute path `/Users/rushabhshah` and the path doesn't exist in CI environment

Comment: Thanks!! Can you let me know how can I resolve that??

Answer (score 1):

Remove the hard-coded path from the build Settings file.
Go to Target - Build Settings - In user Defined Section - Set **FLUTTER_ROOT** and **FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR** to empty i.e. remove hard-coded path
Then push the code with those changes.

Code magic generates build successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're using the UI or .yaml file to build. In case you're using the .yaml make sure that you have `flutter packages pub get` before your build step.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, this script was missing from the `codemagic.yaml` file:

```
xcode-project use-profiles
```

The last line of codemagic's logs for this step reads:

> Saved export options to /Users/builder/export_options.plist